# Java and if NULL

Tags: java, netbeans

I have never done anything in java before so I really am a newb but while building the program I have ran into a snag that i just can't figure out. I will try to explain and show to the best of my abilities.

Here is what I am building 
[The UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvvxU.jpg)
Here is the code I have so far to make it work.

```
    private void jButtonGenerateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    String ObjectName = jtObjectName.getText();
    String ObjectBase = jcbBaseNPC.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String NPCName = jtNPCName.getText();
    String MinLevel = jtMinLevel.getText();
    if (MinLevel != null && MinLevel.isEmpty())
        MinLevel = MinLevel.replace(MinLevel, "minLevel" + MinLevel);{

    }
    //Alignment Combo Box Start
    String Alignment = jcbAlignment.getSelectedItem().toString();               
    if (Alignment.contains("Good")) {
        Alignment = Alignment.replace("Good", "255");            
      }
    if (Alignment.contains("Neutral")) {
        Alignment = Alignment.replace("Neutral", "127");  
    }       
    if (Alignment.contains("Evil")) {
        Alignment = Alignment.replace("Evil", "0");  
    }        
    //Alignment Combo Box End

    // Print to Output Box
    jaOutput.append("object" + " " + ObjectName + " " + "of" + " " + ObjectBase +
     "\n\tproperties" + "\n\tname" +" " + "\"" + NPCName + "\"" + MinLevel      


    );
```

What I can not understand it how to check to see if there is something entered in a String and if there is I need to add to it so the output looks like this.
minLevel 1100
maxLevel 1500

only thing I will be adding is the numbers so i need to add something like 
minLevel + MinLevel

and if it is empty just skip it all together. If I add it to the append and its empty I will just get minLevel and i can't have it like that.
Any tips would be great. 
Thank you all
Donald

Comment: *Unrelated:* Java naming convention is for variable names to start with lowercase letter, e.g. `objectName`, `alignment`, etc.

Comment: It looks like you have the "jButtonGenerateActionPerformed" method showing twice in your post. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Opps no sorry that was a double post

Comment: OK, you should make an edit and get rid of the extra code.

Comment: `MinLevel != null && MinLevel.isEmpty()` you're checking if it's not null and IS empty, you should do this instead `MinLevel != null && !MinLevel.isEmpty()`

Comment: Perfect KeepoN worked